# Devise custom user root is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-routing

After a user signs in, I want them to be redirected to /users/2 or users/44, like a normal resource. (That way an admin can easily view any user's profile page just by knowing their id.)

I have no idea what is going on in my routes file. When a user logs in, I can see in the logs that it authenticates properly, and that my application_controller's `after_sign_in_path_for` is called.

But this is the error that I am getting when I try to redirect_to user_path(current_user).

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :user_id=>11}
```

My `config/routes.rb`

```
  devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_in => 'signin', :sign_out => 'signout', :sign_up => 'signup' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "signin", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "signout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy", via: :delete
    get "signup", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  end

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'settings', to: 'users#edit'
    end
  end
```

My `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to user_path(:user_id=>current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Shouldn't the `resource :users` block take care of creating a user show path? I do have a show method in my users_controller.rb. Please help, I've been trying to get this working for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was `redirect`ing in the after_sign_in_path(resource) method instead of just returning the path:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return user_path(:user_id=>current_user.id)
  end
```

is the correct way to do this.